# boost::asio read/write trouble

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I started to learn the boost::asio and tried to make simple client-server application. At now I have troubles with server. Here it code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::asio;

    io_service service;
    ip::tcp::endpoint endp(ip::tcp::v4(), 2001);
    ip::tcp::acceptor acc(service, endp);

    for (;;)
    {
        socker_ptr sock(new ip::tcp::socket(service));
        acc.accept(*sock);
        for (;;)
        {
            byte data[512];

            size_t len = sock->read_some(buffer(data));  // <--- here exception at second iteration

            if (len > 0)
                write(*sock, buffer("ok", 2));
        }
    }
}
```

It correctly accepted the client socket, correctly read, then it write data and strarted new iteration. On second iteration throwed exception. It looks like:
[image]
 And I don`t get why it happens?
I just need that server must read/write continuosly while the client present. And when the client gone the server must accept next client.

So the main question: why excpection happens and what how to aviod it?

...

UPDATE1: I found that at first iteration the error code of both read/write operation is successful. But (!) on second iteration at place where exception reised the error code is "End of file". But why?

Comment: You should be passing in the maximum size of the buffer ( 512 ) as a second parameter to the buffer for read_some.  I doubt this is the root cause, however there is no reasonable method for buffer to determine the length of the byte array.

Comment: Hmm, this does not help. I note that the first iteration completely passed fine, but on second iteration it fails. I tried to add the size of the buffer "size_t len = sock->read_some(buffer(data, 512));". But it not helps. The trouble is still present.

Comment: @sehe: #tmyk!  Thanks for pointing this out. I was unaware there was a technique for the compiler to automatically detect the number of elements within an array.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Cheers :) I've spent years on SO learning these things, among others, it is really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the end of file condition because the remote end of the connection closed or dropped the connection.

You should be handling the system errors, or using the overloads that take a reference to `boost::system::error_code`. How else would you ever terminate the infinite loop?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9035fbb4b46dea92)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;

    io_service service;
    ip::tcp::endpoint endp(ip::tcp::v4(), 2001);
    ip::tcp::acceptor acc(service, endp);

    for (;;)
    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        acc.accept(sock);
        boost::system::error_code ec;

        while (!ec)
        {
            uint8_t data[512];

            size_t len = sock.read_some(buffer(data), ec);

            if (len > 0)
            {
                std::cout << "received " << len << " bytes\n";
                write(sock, buffer("ok", 2));
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Closed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    }
}
```